# java android pass resource file path to a method parameter

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, jdom

I have an xml file under res folder, the structure is res/raw/myfile.xml. Now i am using JDOM for parsing the file using SAXBuilder.build("raw/myfile.xml"); 
And in Logcat it is showing that it cannot open the file.
How can I achieve this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you parse a raw resource called `myfile.xml`:

```
InputStream input = context.getResources().openRawResource(com.YourApp.R.raw.myfile);
Document doc = DocumentBuilder.parse(input);
```

**Note1** Notice that there is no file extension at the end of `com.YourApp.R.raw.myfile`! (so you cannot have two different files with same name)
**Note2** You cannot make sub folders under raw folder!
**Note3** If I remeber correctly, your file name should have all lower case and no spaces!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this'll help:

[Referring to Android Resources Using URIs](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html)

As soon as you've built your URI you can easily get the path as a string and pass it to the parser. See [URI documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) (method getPath)